# Do EU residents need visa to travel to USA?

Tags: visas, usa, europe, spain, working-visas

I am working in Spain as a Turkish citizen. I have a residence/working card for one year. I will need to go to US this spring. I am wondering if I am required to have a tourist visa for this or I am eligible to travel with just my residence/working card and an ESTA.

Comment: EU citizens generally need an ESTA, it seems unlikely that EU residents need *less* paperwork.

Comment: It depends on the country. Citizens of some EU countries need a full-fledged visa to US. So as @o.m. said it would be surprising if being a "resident" in Spain would help with anything.

Comment: If you _need_ to go to the US, that implies you'll be going for work purposes. If so, a tourist visa won't do, and you'll need an appropriate work visa. Tourist visas are only for people who _want_ to visit the US, not for people who _need_ to.

Comment: If ESTA will not give you allowance, you still need a visa. Here is [a nice statistics about](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Statistics/Non-Immigrant-Statistics/RefusalRates/FY16.pdf) vista refusal (including visa free countries).

Comment: @MikeScott the visa waiver program accommodates both visitors for business and visitors for pleasure.  People who need a visa require a B-1 visa for business visits or a B-2 visa for pleasure visits, but the vast majority of visitor visas issued by the US are combination B-1/B-2, so they also accommodate both classes of visitor.

Comment: Relevant to the poster: Spain visa refusal rate is higher than Turkey.

Comment: @gnasher729 That’s hardly surprising, because since Spain is covered by the visa waiver programme the only Spanish citizens applying for visas will be those who aren’t eligible for a visa waiver, which will be the more difficult cases.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Whether you need a visa to visit the US is based on your *citizenship*, not your *residence*. So, as a citizen of Turkey you will need a visa to visit the US.

Answer (score 20):

Your Spanish work permit is not relevant and Turkey is not a US Visa Waiver country, so you need a visa to enter the United States.

[Here are the official details.](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en.html)

Answer (score 12):

Turkish citizens **do** need a visa for the US, as stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=TR&AR=ES&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=US&&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C). Foreign residency is completely irrelevant

Comment: The question is somewhat understandable if one considers the situation in Europe, where having a Schengen visa allows visits to some non-Schengen nations. That doesn't change the answer, of course.

Comment: @o.m. That's what I meant - in some countries foreign residency is relevant, but the US is not one of them

Comment: Obviously, foreign residency _is_ relevant when you need to provide current address details when applying for US visa. Don't use an old Turkish address there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you mostly definitely need a visa.

Be aware that foreigners seeking a visa while residing in a foreign country may have difficulty proving strong ties to his current residence. Prepare any document that shows ties (wage slips, job contract, assets) to your EU residence, and proof of funds to afford your trip to the US.